# Finding duplicate blocks of text within a file using shell script

Tags: text-processing

Say I have a text file with the following lines:-

```
abcd/efgh/a.jar
{
abcd/efgh/a.class
cdef/ghij/b.class
klmn/opqr/c.class
}
lkmn/opqr/b.zip
{
abcd/efgh/a.class
cdef/ghij/b.class
}
abcd/efgh/a.jar
{
cdef/ghij/b.class
}
```

Now abcd/efgh/a.jar in the first case has abcd/efgh/a.class, cdef/ghij/b.class and klmn/opqr/c.class within the curly braces. Consider it as 1 block of text. Now abcd/efgh/a.jar below again has cdef/ghij/b.class within curly braces. I want to remove this section/block of text. So the final output needs to be like:-

```
abcd/efgh/a.jar
{
abcd/efgh/a.class
cdef/ghij/b.class
klmn/opqr/c.class
}
lkmn/opqr/b.zip
{
abcd/efgh/a.class
cdef/ghij/b.class
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: What if the second `a.jar` block contains `d.class`? Add it to the first block or leave it as a block of it's own?

Comment: Good question. If the second a.jar has a d.class, then it needs to be merged to the first block. So the first a.jar block needs to have d.class as well

Comment: I expanded your example to include this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
for i in `awk '/}/ {if (NR!=1) print "";next} \
                {printf "%s ",$0,"}"}END{print ""}' yt.txt \
        |awk '{print $1}'|sort|uniq \
    `; \
    do \
        awk '/}/ {if (NR!=1) print "";next} \
            {printf "%s ",$0,"}"}END{printf ""} \
            ' yt.txt \
         |grep "$i"|sed 's/ /\n/g'|grep -v "$i"|sort|uniq \
            |awk -v var="$i" ' NR==1 {printf var} {print $0} END {print "}"}'  \
    ;done \
```

Same command in 1 line below (for copying purpose)

```
for i in `awk '/}/ {if (NR!=1) print "";next} {printf "%s ",$0,"}"}END{print ""}' yt.txt|awk '{print $1}'|sort|uniq` ; do awk '/}/ {if (NR!=1) print "";next} {printf "%s ",$0,"}"}END{printf ""}' yt.txt|grep "$i"|sed 's/ /\n/g'|grep -v "$i"|sort|uniq|awk -v var="$i" ' NR==1 {printf var} {print $0} END {print "}"}' ;done
```

Explanation:

The `for` part will return you the unique heading of the block (`abcd/efgh/a.jar`,`lkmn/opqr/b.zip`) and pass it to `do` block. The `do` part will first `grep` all the rows for each heading, which would include duplicates also. Then it will exclude the heading and merge all the remaining rows under that heading block, then add the heading at first row. And hardcode `}` at the end.

Example

```
bash-4.2$ cat yt.txt
abcd/efgh/a.jar
{
abcd/efgh/a.class
cdef/ghij/b.class
klmn/opqr/c.class
}
lkmn/opqr/b.zip
{
abcd/efgh/a.class
cdef/ghij/b.class
}
abcd/efgh/a.jar
{
cdef/ghij/b.class
d.class
}



bash-4.2$ for i in `awk '/}/ {if (NR!=1) print "";next} {printf "%s ",$0,"}"} \
> END{print ""}' yt.txt |awk '{print $1}'|sort|uniq` \
> ; do awk '/}/ {if (NR!=1) print "";next} {printf "%s ",$0,"}"}END{printf ""}' yt.txt \
>  |grep "$i"|sed 's/ /\n/g'|grep -v "$i"|sort|uniq \
> |awk -v var="$i" ' NR==1 {printf var} {print $0} END {print "}"}'\
> ;done
abcd/efgh/a.jar
{
abcd/efgh/a.class
cdef/ghij/b.class
d.class
klmn/opqr/c.class
}
lkmn/opqr/b.zip
{
abcd/efgh/a.class
cdef/ghij/b.class
}
```

Comment: Happy to help. Feel free to accept the answer so the question could be closed

Answer (score 1):

After I saw the solution utilizing a `for` loop with `awk` and `sort` and `uniq` and `grep` and `sed` I tried a solution with one tool instead of six:

```
sed ':a
  N;$!ba
  y/\n_/_\n/;s/^/_/
  :b
  s/\(_[^_]*_{\)\([^}]*\)\(_[^_}]*\)\(_[^}]*\)\(_}.*\)\1\([^}]*\)\3_/\1\2\3\4\5\1\6_/;tb
  :c
  s/\(_[^_]*_{\)\([^}]*\)_}\(.*\)\1\([^}]*\)_}/\1\2\4_}\3/;tc
  s/^_//
  y/\n_/_\n/' yourfile
```

does the job, but I have to admit that the regular expressions are easiert to write than to read ... (-;

Comment: So you started to use the `y/\n_/_\n/`  now ;-)

Comment: @RakeshSharma Indeed. But I still dislike it! (-;  Well, for a messy script like this it doesn't matter. In real life I would use python instead for a task like this. Thank you once again for introducing me to that workaround.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -alF'/\n[}{]\n/' -0777ne '
   for ( 0 .. $#F/2 ) {
      my $i = 2*$_;
      my($k,$v) = @F[$i,$i+1];
      if ( exists $h{$k} ) {
         $h{$k} .= join $\, grep { ! exists $seen{$k,$_} } split $\, $v;
      } else {
         push @k, $k;
         $seen{$k,$_}++ for split $\, $h{$k} = $v;
      }
   }
   print "$_\n{\n$h{$_}\n}" for @k;
' yourfile
```

---

### Results

```
abcd/efgh/a.jar
{
abcd/efgh/a.class
cdef/ghij/b.class
klmn/opqr/c.class
}
lkmn/opqr/b.zip
{
abcd/efgh/a.class
cdef/ghij/b.class
}
```

---

### Working

The input file is slurped and then split up into fields based on the field separator mentioned by the `-F` option. We will be getting even number of elements in the array `@F`. The even numbered then go in as the keys of the hash `%h` whilst their corresp. values are grabbed from the next odd value.

The hash `%h` is populated by splitting up the odd numbered elems on record separator ($\ = \n). At the same time we place the key into the array `@k` so that we can retrieve hash elements in order they were encountered.

All the while only those odd elements are used that are not already seen.